# OpenLayers. Slow map after render heatmap even when I clear the layer source

Tags: openlayers, heat-map

I'm working in a map with about 10 layers and it works fine, when I create a heatmap it becomes slower, that's something I was expecting, because the source has about 2000 points. When I want to make the heatmap disapear I just clear the layer source, but the map continues very slow.

Check out my code:

```
let map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults({attribution:false}).extend([
        expandedAttribution
    ]),
    target: document.getElementById('map'),
    renderer: 'canvas',
    overlays: [overlayPopup],
    layers: layersList,
    view: new ol.View({
     extent: extent, 
     maxZoom: maxZoom, 
     minZoom: minZoom, 
    }),
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
        doubleClickZoom: false
    })
});

let data = new ol.source.Vector();
//I create the heatmap with a empty vector
let heatMapLayer = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
    source: data,
    radius: 10
});
map.addLayer(heatMapLayer);

//*******************************************************************
//To add the source
let coord = ol.proj.fromLonLat([ocor.longitude, ocor.latitude]);  
let lonLat = new ol.geom.Point(coord);
let pointFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: lonLat,
    weight: 20 // e.g. temperature
});
dataHeatmap.addFeature(pointFeature);
heatMapLayer.setSource(dataHeatmap);

//******************************************************************
//and to remove the heatmap:

heatMapLayer.getSource().clear();
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.